# how GPU will behave with different NDRange calls?

Tags: opencl

I had a rough day in understanding workitems/workgroups/warps/threads.. i am running program on GPU.. some are helping.. some are not... I want to know where i am going wrong. Please help me out for some basic logics.

as per my understanding in NDRangekernel,

```
global_work_size: how many workgroups
local_work_size: how many workitems in each workgroup
```

so, if i say for WG,WI = 1024,1024 -> it means 1024 * 1024 jobs will be invoked? I am understanding here 1024 workgroups will be invoked and each workgroup will have 1024 workitem, hence kernel will be executed for 1024 * 1024 times.

**Question1:** Is above statement true??

**Question2:** then where warp came into picture? What is actually warp logic doing here?

**Question3:** how many tasks will be launched if i execute following statement:

```
size_t glob = 1024;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &glob, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);
```

**Question4:** how many tasks will be launched if i execute following statement:

```
size_t glob = 1024;
size_t loc = 1;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &glob, &loc, 0, NULL, &event);
```

**Question5:** how many tasks will be launched if i execute following statement:

```
size_t glob = 1024;
size_t loc = 1024;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &glob, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);
```

**Question6:** Some profilers like computeprof etc gave data like warps_launched, threads_launched, active_warps, active_cycles?? What are these?? what is the logic of thread here??

P.S. these are not assignment questions.. i really want to know what is going on GPU when i am launching kernel... Please help me out..

Comment: The details of warps etc. may be tricky and of course hardware dependent, and OpenCL deliberately tries to **abstract** from the hardware. Just concerning the first question: "*global_work_size: how many workgroups*" - this is **NOT** the case. The global work size is the total global work size. When the global work size is 10000, then there will be 10000 "jobs" (as you call it). Consequently, you have to make sure that the global work size is a multiple of the local work size. (Expliclity *specifying* the latter is mainly relevant when you use local memory - otherwise, you may pass in `null`)

Comment: Thanks @Marco13 means if i am calling (1024,256) (1024,512) (1024,1024), it means 1024 jobs will be executed all the time.. this i got... but then what 256/512/1024 will decide?

Comment: The answer to "Which local work size (LWS) should I use?" will hardly fit into a comment. Just short: When you use local memory you have to *specify* the LWS, because the number has to *match* the size of the local memory. Otherwise, you can choose it rather freely - 32 will work and 256 will work. But it will affect the occupancy (how good the processing resources are used). In the end, the question of how all this is mapped to the hardware (in terms of warps etc) depends on the OpenCL implementation. Using `null` as LWS leaves the decision to the OpenCL impl., which can be fine in many cases

Comment: no no no.. @Marco13 i was asking what will be the affect if i launch NDRangekernel by 1024 GWS and any number for LWS like 256/512/1024 or any multiple number?? what is the actual use of this argument if jobs are going to be 1024 only?? Please be patient and help me out..

Comment: @Marco13 please correct me if i am wrong.. If GWS=1024 and LWS=16. then NDRange sizeX = 64 and workgroupsizeX=16; which means occupancy will be 16/64 = 0.25 processing resources are not used properly

Comment: Again: The OpenCL implementation will decide how this is mapped to hardware. For NVIDIA, you can imagine the structure roughly like this http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/graphics/grid-of-thread-blocks.png : The "grid" is the global work size, and the "blocks" are the local work size. The occupancy then depends on the hardware, you may compute it with http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if i say for WG,WI = 1024,1024 -> it means 1024 * 1024 jobs will be invoked? I am understanding here 1024 workgroups will be invoked and each workgroup will have 1024 workitem, hence kernel will be executed for 1024 * 1024 times.
>
> Question1: Is above statement true??

No. This is how CUDA kernel launches are described (with block sizes and grid sizes), but OpenCL takes a different approach. The global work size is the total number of *work-items*, not the number of work-groups. The local work size is just how many work-items to put in each work-group; this parameter has absolutely no effect on how many work-items are launched in total.

---

> Question2: then where warp came into picture? What is actually warp logic doing here?

Many of the devices that run OpenCL execute small groups of work-items in a SIMD fashion. That is, these groups of work-items execute the same instruction at the same time. On NVIDIA hardware, these are called warps, and contain 32 work-items. On AMD hardware, they are called wavefronts, and contain 64 work-items. The OpenCL programming model doesn't really expose these SIMD groups to the programmer, although you can query the preferred work-group size multiple (by passing `CL_KERNEL_PREFERRED_WORK_GROUP_SIZE_MULTIPLE` to `clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo`), which gives an indication of what this size is. OpenCL 2.0 has a `cl_khr_subgroups` extension which also starts to expose these things, and offers some synchronisation primitives that can be efficiently implemented on these devices.

---

> Question3: how many tasks will be launched if i execute following statement:
>
> ```
> size_t glob = 1024;
> clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &glob, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);
> ```

This will launch 1024 work-items. This size of the work-group will be selected by the implementation at runtime.

---

> Question4: how many tasks will be launched if i execute following statement:
>
> ```
> size_t glob = 1024;
> size_t loc = 1;
> clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &glob, &loc, 0, NULL, &event);
> ```

This will also launch 1024 work-items, but will insist that they are in work-groups of size 1.

---

> Question5: how many tasks will be launched if i execute following statement:
>
> ```
> size_t glob = 1024;
> size_t loc = 1024;
> clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &glob, NULL, 0, NULL, &event);
> ```

This will also launch 1024 work-items, but they will be in a single work-group.

---

> Question6: Some profilers like computeprof etc gave data like warps_launched, threads_launched, active_warps, active_cycles?? What are these?? what is the logic of thread here??

In the case of NVIDIA hardware, a thread is a single work-item. The [NVIDIA NVVP documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#metrics-reference) is the best place to get detailed descriptions of what each of these individual metrics mean.

Comment: thanks @jprice... one more query.. does warp in CUDA is equivalent to workgroup size in OpenCl?? and why i want to control this size?

Comment: for controlling its size... reason depends on the way of implementation... correct?

Comment: @Vishwadeep No, a warp is a hardware specific characteristic which you cannot control. A work-group contains a number of work-items that execute on the same compute unit, which means that they share local memory and synchronise with each other. Each work-group will consist of one or more warps/wavefronts/etc.